# SoX Not Reading Wav

Tags: audio, sox

I've got a large (5Gb) WAV 64 file that I'm trying to analyse with SoX. On doing;

sox /file/ -n stats

it tells me;

sox FAIL formats: can't open input file '/file/': WAVE: RIFF header not found

On attempting to specify;

sox /file/ -t w64 -n stats

it says;

sox WARN sox: ignoring `-t w64'.

and proceeds to throw the same error as before. This file is W64. How do I convince SoX to accept it?

Comment: It maybe a raw file. Not a `wav` file!

Comment: Why do you have `/file/` instead of something like `./file` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ffmpeg can handle wav64 files

Have you tried to create your own tiny wav64 file and see if you can read that ?

Looks like wav64 is targeted for multichannel audio is that your use case ?  WAV format itself is very simple and lends itself to allowing people to write two pages of code to read any wav file ... if you exhaust all other options and your life depended on getting your file read,  reading the ISO spec or similar on wav64 format then writing your own reader is an option.

Can you share how your wav64 file was created ?  Maybe one of us can replicate its creation and battle how to read it back

If its not full of massive multi-channel audio is getting it converted to normal wav an option ?

Comment: It's a WAV conversion of a multichannel DSD file from an SACD. Since it's bigger than 4Gb I can't use standard WAV. I'll try and see if I can work around it; there are other ways I can deal with the source material that doesn't require SoX to read it. It's simply that I believe that it's WAV64 since the trustworthy program that output it said it was, so I don't know why SoX refuses to accept that even when I tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe, your `wave64` file is invalid. A valid one should contain a `riff` header.
>   
>   You've added `-t w64` flag after the filename. That's why it's ignored.

```sh
# This would work!  [CHECKED]
# If your file is valid!
sox -t w64 in_file -n stats
```

Comment: I tested ur way but not work with the last version of sox: `sox FAIL formats: no handler for given file type "w64"`